# Proof by contradiction: the intersection of any collection of non-empty convex sets is convex

Tags: solution-verification, convex-analysis

Looking for feedback on how the below can possibly be simplified, or if it's even correct!

Let $S_{i}$ be a convex set for $i = 1, 2, ..., n$.

Suppose $S = \cap_{i=1}^{n} S_{i}$ and $\exists x_{1}, x_{2} \in S$ such that $\alpha x_{1} + (1-\alpha) x_{2} \notin S$, with $\alpha \in [0, 1]$

Then $\forall S_{i}$, $(x_{1}, x_{2} \in S_{i}) \land (\alpha x_{1} + (1-\alpha) x_{2} \notin S_{i}$).

This is a contradiction as by definition of a convex set:

$\exists x_{1}, x_{2} \in S_{i} \Rightarrow \alpha x_{1} + (1-\alpha) x_{2} \in S_{i}$, with $\alpha \in [0, 1]$.

**Edit**:

Responding to Tomasz' comment, here's an additional attempt at a proof:

Let $\{S_{d}\}_{d \in D}$ be some arbitrary collection of non-empty convex sets with index $d$ and $S = \bigcap_{d \in D}S_{d}$.

$\exists x_{1}, x_{2} \in S \Rightarrow x_{1}, x_{2} \in S_{d}, \forall d \in D$

Then by definition of a convex set, all points of the form $\alpha x_{1} + (1 - \alpha) x_{2}$ with $\alpha \in [0,1]$ are in $S_{d}$ $\forall d \in D$ and $\alpha x_{1} + (1 - \alpha) x_{2} \in S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is basically correct, except it is not *really* a proof by contradiction.

It would be more clear if you restated it as a direct proof (that it essentially is).

Further, there is an issue in that in the statement you write "any collection", while in your proof you act as if the collection was finite. This does not really affect the reasoning in any meaningful way, but you should be careful what you write.

**Edit** regarding the updated proof: it is essentially correct, but there are serious issues with the notation:

- The quantifier $\exists x_1,x_2$ does not make sense. You are checking that the following holds for each pair $x_1,x_2$. not assuming that a pair exists.
- Writing the quantifier $\forall d\in D$ after the variable it's supposed to bind is bad form.
- Overall, using too many symbols in mathematical prose is bad form and makes things hard to read (it's different when you're writing on blackboard and saying out loud what you mean, but when you want to communicate math via text alone, this is just not a good idea).
- It does not make sense to talk of "sets with index $d$". $d$ is just a symbol for an element of $D$. What would make sense would be to say that it is a family indexed by $D$ (capital). In fact, you can dispense with the index set altogether, and just write that you have a family $\mathcal S$ of convex sets and $S=\bigcap \mathcal S$, but that is largely a matter of taste.

A better way to write this is as follows.

Let $\mathcal S$ be some arbitrary collection of non-empty convex sets and $S = \bigcap \mathcal S$.

We will show that $S$ is convex. It suffices to show that for each $x_1,x_2\in S$ and $\alpha\in [0,1]$, the combination $\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2\in S$.

Fix an arbitrary $S'\in \mathcal S$. Then $S\subseteq S'$, so $x_1,x_2\in S'$, and since $S'$ is convex, $\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2\in S'$. But since $S'\in \mathcal S$ was arbitrary, we have that $$\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2\in \bigcap \mathcal S=S,$$ which completes the proof. $\square$

(By the way, there is no reason to assume that the collection consists of nonempty sets. Empty set is also convex. Otherwise, if you don't consider the empty set to be convex, then the proposition is false: the intersection of non-empty convex sets can be empty.)

Comment: Appreciate the feedback!  Added an edit that attempts to be more of a direct proof and also deals with the arbitrary collection of sets issue.  Does that look better?

Comment: Thanks once again!  I was seriously struggling with the proper notation for an arbitrary collection of sets last night, especially since I wanted to leave open the possibility of this collection being uncountable.  Good point on the messiness as well; after sleeping on it, it certainly looks like I got a bit carried away!  On excluding the empty set, that was intentional as I had already come across a proof by contradiction that I felt good about. 
 Overall I really appreciate the lengthy feedback here; it will certainly be helpful as I continue to attempt various proofs!

Comment: @hillard28: Regarding arbitrary collections, insisting on having an index set makes sense when we want to stress that the collection is countable, or if we have some more structure on it (so it is not just a set, but say, a poset). But any collection can be thought of as indexed in the following way: $\mathcal S$ is the same as $\{S_S\mid S\in \mathcal S\}$, where $S_S=S$. (Mind, this is really bad form in many ways, but I think it's a good illustration in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

A proof by contradiction should go as follows.

Assume that the intersection is not convex then there exist

$x,y \in\,\bigcap\,K_{i}$ such that for some $\lambda$ in

$[0,1]\,\,\, \lambda\,x+(1-\lambda)y \notin\,\bigcap\,K_{i}$

But $x,y \in K_{i}$ for all $i$ and hence $\lambda\,x+(1-\lambda)y\,\in \,K_{i}$

for all $i$ and hence $\lambda\,x+(1-\lambda)y\,\in \,\bigcap\,K_{i}$, contradiction!!

Comment: Thanks, George!  It's been a while since I've written any proofs and had fudged the typical $(\sim R) \Rightarrow P$ convention!